# Is [Serializable] needed to reuse types in referenced assemblies under WCF?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, serialization, .net-4.0

A while ago I learnt about the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" WCF option through [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14937718/210818). Our aim was to use this option to share a set of class libraries between client and server; these libraries implement our business object model and both the server exposing the WCF services and the clients consuming them will need to use them. We are using .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010.

We run some test scenarios and everything seemed to work fine. However, now we are mid-way through product development, and we have found out that WCF apparently requires the shared classes to be marked as serializable. We didn't mark them as such in our preliminary tests and everything worked OK, so I am confused as to why we are now getting an WCF error asking us to mark them as serializable. From what I've read, it seems related to some classes not having a parameterless constructor, but I am not sure about this.

My question is: do we need to make our shared classes serializable, or is there a workaround? Are there any best practices or well known strategy to prepare a class library for being shared between client and server in a WCF setting? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is not using a WSDL at all but instead sharing the same dll by adding it as a reference to the client. Check out how your proxy code (reference.cs) looks now. There may be specific clienty classes (inherit from ClientBase) which you can leave, but the main code is in your data contract / serializable classes which you can get via add dll reference.

Comment: I am not sure if I am following you. As I describe in the OP, we are already planning to share the same DLL by adding it as a reference to the client. Problem is, this approach apparently needs the classes in the DLL to be marked as Serializable, and hence my question. Any comments to this?

Comment: http://jamesheppinstall.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/windows-communication-foundation-consuming-a-wcf-service-with-channelfactory/